# How to make a few lines of function execute only once in python? preferably using lambda?

Tags: python, function

I have one python function as shown below.

```
def save_eng(request):
    flag = "true"
    if flag == "true" :
        db = Create()
        db.CreateSubmit_EngineerTable()
        flag = "false"
    else:
        pass
```

Now I want to call the CreateSubmit_Engineer() only once i.e when its called for the first time. I'll be calling this function many times but it shouldn't create the table again and again. I have used the flag variable which isn't solving my purpose.The flag gets assigned to "true" value when I'm calling this function. I know I'm so close just need small hint.Any help is greatly appreciated. Can the above function be written in any other better way ?

Comment: Python doesn't need backets around `if`.

Comment: put `flag` outside the function?

Comment: Also, why are you using the strings `"true"` and `"false"` instead of the boolean values `True` and `False` (which would also allow you to change that `if` to the more idiomatic `if flag:`)?

Comment: @simonzack I know but as it doesn't mind I still use it. :)

Comment: @ssm : Thanks. I knew I was close. It's working now.

Comment: @sammy: That makes your code less idiomatic and less readable. You can also throw semicolons all over the place, name all your variables in all caps, alternate single-space and 6-tabs indents, and break each line up into separate 1-character lines with `\` continuations and Python doesn't mind… but code is for human readers first, and compilers second.

Comment: @abarnert : I'll be using the boolean values right away in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Not that I'm suggesting this, but… you could abuse [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) here. Since your function takes no arguments and is only called for side-effects, all calls after the first will hit the same cached `None` result and not run the function. But again, you shouldn't do that; use Ashwini's answer for a decorator that actually says what it's doing.

Comment: @abarnert : I see. Now I have edited the code in my question. It's been a month or so exploring the python. Next time I'll keep this in mind.Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a decorator for this.

Using class based decorator:

```
class callonce(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.called = False

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.called:
            self.called = True
            return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'Function already called once.'
```

Using function attribute:

```
from functools import wraps

def callonce(f):

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not wrapper.called:
            wrapper.called = True
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'Function already called once.'
    wrapper.called = False
    return wrapper
```

Now add the decorator above your function:

```
@callonce
def func():
    print "Creating Table"
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> func()
Creating Table
>>> func()
Function already called once.
>>> func()
Function already called once.
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to python. I have to figure it out what you many things that you wrote in your code :)

Comment: @sammy: It might be worth splitting this into three parts. First: functions are objects, just like anything else in Python, and you can attach attributes to them. This is one way of storing information across runs. (Other ways include global and nonlocal variables, and mutable default argument values.) So, instead of having a local `flag` that's re-created each time you call the function, you have `save_eng.flag`, which is created once and re-used each time you call the function.

Comment: @sammy: The second part is `*args, **kwargs`. If you want to take whatever arguments the caller throws at you, you can capture the regular arguments in a list with `*args`, and the keyword arguments in a dict with `**kwargs`. And then you can use that list and dict to pass the same arguments on to another function. This allows you to write a "proxy" that can sit in front of any other function, without having to know what arguments that other function wants.

Comment: @sammy: Finally, there's decorators. These are just functions that can take functions and return other functions. In this case, Ashwini wrote a function, `callonce`, that takes a function, adds the `.flag` attribute to it, and returns a proxy to that function that uses `*args, **kwargs`, and checks the flag before calling the real function. Once you understand these three pieces, everything in Ashwini's answer is simple (except maybe how `@wraps` works, but you can put that off for later)—and so are a whole lot of other things you don't even yet know that you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use a class here. Put the code to create the table on constructor i.e. `__init__(self)` and then create an object of the class and call the save_eng() as many times as per your requirement

```
Class Engineer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Create()
        self.db.CreateSubmit_EngineerTable()
    def save_eng(self, request):
        # Your other code specific to save_eng
        # you can use self.db here
        pass


# Create instance of class
eng = Engineer()
eng.save_eng(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not pass any parameters, you can use functools.lru_cache:

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def func():
    print "Creating Table"
```